# Can Outlook add-ins made with Office.js monitor incoming mail?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, vsto, office-js

So we are consider migrating a moderately complex Outlook VSTO add-in to Office.js to make it cross-platform. I have been reading for some time, but things appear to be convoluted. Specifically I have been trying to figure out the following:

1. Does Office.js have a way to monitor incoming e-mails? VSTO can easily do this.
2. Does Office.js allow iterating through local mailboxes (POP or IMAP), also called `Stores` in VSTO? Can we also access folders and MailItems therein?
3. How does Graph API fit into the picture? Can Graph API be used with Yahoo or Gmail mailboxes, or only with hotmail.com and outlook.com accounts?

Hope someone could help me with the answers.

Answer (score 0):

1. Currently no, you'd need to use Graph for that, from a backend application, and subscribe to new email notifications
2. No, and also office.js does not support POP or IMAP accounts
3. I'm not a Graph expert, so can't really answer this. I think only hotmail.com, outlook.com and Office365 accounts, but there may be some capabilities that may allow to use it for gmail too (but likely not Yahoo).